# AngularJS http.put multiple requestBody

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible with AngularJS http.put to send more than one requestBody to server.
My frontend Angular put method looks like this:

```
function XY() {
    return $http.put(url, data1, data2);
```

and my backend method looks like this:

```
public @ResponseBody Boolean myBackendMethod(@PathVariable ..., final @RequestBody(required = true) Object data1,
        final @RequestBody(required = true) Object data2)
```

In this case **data2** is not sent to backend. Is there a possibility to do it like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Passing multiple data to `$http.put` is not supported. According to the **[documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#put)**, the syntax of put function is

```
put(url, data, [config]);
```

As you can see, since the third parameter is `[config]`, you can not pass here the data to be posted.

The simpler approach would be to have a container wrapper object for holding both the *data's*. Send this container as data and handle it in your back-end method.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new object

```
var returnData = { data1 : data1, data2 : data2 }
return $http.put(url, returnData);
```